Spring Transaction Rollback
I have functions, and this functions will go on catch conditions.
My expectations whenever it goes to catch conditions it should've rollback the previous save data. but why the data is still saved on the DB without rollback. even i already use annotation @Transactional
@Transactional
public RpaLog createRpaLogObject(CreateRpaLogObjectRequest request) {
    RpaLog rpaLog = new RpaLog();
    try {
        rpaLog.setFunctionName(request.getFunctionName());
        rpaLog.setStatus(request.getStatus());
        rpaLog.setCreatedDate(HelperUtils.getCurrentTimestamp());
        rpaLog = rpaLogRepository.save(rpaLog);

        String externalApiUrl = rpaConfig.getEndpoint() + rpaLog.getId();
        restTemplate.getForObject(
                externalApiUrl,
                ExternalApiResponse.class
        );
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new CreationFailedException(MessageConstants.RPA_CREATION_FAILED + request.getFunctionName());
    }

    return rpaLog;
}

i used Spring Data Commons - CrudRepository package by the way.
How can i achieve the rollback ?
I've test like this also to force the rollback,
but it seems doesnt trigger the rollback at all
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public RpaLog createRpaLogObject(CreateRpaLogObjectRequest request) {
    RpaLog rpaLog = new RpaLog();
    rpaLog.setFunctionName(request.getFunctionName());
    rpaLog.setStatus(request.getStatus());
    rpaLog.setCreatedDate(HelperUtils.getCurrentTimestamp());
    rpaLog = rpaLogRepository.save(rpaLog);

    throw new RuntimeException("Throw example");
}


Is this method is called from another method that is not annotated with @Transactional? If so, the transaction may not behave as expected.

yes that service method called from controller method here ....
@PostMapping()
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public BaseObjectApiResponse createRpaLogObject(@RequestBody CreateRpaLogObjectRequest request) {
RpaLog rpaLogRecord = rpaLogService.createRpaLogObject(request);
return new BaseObjectApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK, rpaLogRecord, MessageConstants.DATA_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY);
}

so I don't see @Transactional annotation, - or I'm wrong? Is it there?

yes it's not there, do i really need to add on controller level ? i've tried to add but the result still same

yes, keep it there. Also see my answer-post, - update annotation and debug again.

also, please update post with markdown code-chunk of that "service method called from controller method"

Also, by default, the @Transactional annotation will only roll back transactions for unchecked exceptions (i.e., subclasses of RuntimeException). If your CreationFailedException is a checked exception, the transaction will not roll back automatically.

Also, consider the isolation level of your transaction. If it's set to a level that prevents visibility of uncommitted changes, it might affect how rollbacks are perceived. You can specify the isolation level in the @Transactional annotation.

Thanks man, that isolation level resolved my issue

Try to modify your code like following:
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public RpaLog createRpaLogObject(CreateRpaLogObjectRequest request) {
    // your code
}


To test if the rollback works, simulate an exception in the try block (e.g., by throwing a RuntimeException) and check if the data is rolled back in the database.
Update: By default, the @Transactional annotation will only roll back transactions for unchecked exceptions (i.e., subclasses of RuntimeException). If your CreationFailedException is a checked exception, the transaction will not roll back automatically.
Also: Consider the isolation level of your transaction. If it's set to a level that prevents visibility of uncommitted changes, it might affect how rollbacks are perceived. You can specify the isolation level in the @Transactional annotation.

I've tried like this also,
to test out the transaction, anything wrong with my entity setting or what ya ?
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public RpaLog createRpaLogObject(CreateRpaLogObjectRequest request) {
RpaLog rpaLog = new RpaLog();
rpaLog.setFunctionName(request.getFunctionName());
rpaLog.setStatus(request.getStatus());
rpaLog.setCreatedDate(HelperUtils.getCurrentTimestamp());
rpaLog = rpaLogRepository.save(rpaLog);
    throw new RuntimeException("Throw example");
}


Mate, please do no write code in comments - it is impossible to read. Instead, try edit your question-post with these code chunks marked down.

ah ok, I see updates, cool

Broo, how come ? ... after i added the isolation now able to rollback.
what is the reason. thanks man

My bad, i put transaction isolation level to none on database config, damn. thanks bro
